# Existence of zero divisors in prime ideals

Tags: ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If we take a commutative ring $R$ whose prime ideal $I$ is considered for presence of zero divisors. I found the following reasoning:

> $I$ is a *prime ideal* implies $I$ has no zero divisors.

**FALSE**: If $I$ is a prime ideal, this is equivalent to $R/I$ being an integral domain. But that concludes nothing about $I$. Thus $I$ may or may not have zero divisors.

*The converse may not hold true in general, that is:*

> If an Ideal $I$ has no zero divisors, then it may not necessarily be a
>   prime ideal.

I found the supporting counterexample:

$4Z$ is an ideal of $Z$ without zero divisors, but $4Z$ is not a prime ideal of $Z$ which can be checked easily.

Please verify if my arguments are valid. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does $R/I$ being an integral domain imply $I$ is an integral domain as well? In fact, [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67382/minimal-primes-and-zero-divisors) shows that every non-zero element of a minimal prime is a zero-divisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by awllower, your first claim is incorrect.

The ideal $\mathbb{C}\times\{0\}$ of $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ is prime, since the corresponding quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ , but $(1,0)\in\mathbb{C}\times\{0\}$  is a zero divisor.